# Word-making game

Tags: combinatorics, game

I like to play a game with my family and friends. It goes like this:

The players take turns to say a letter. The letters taken in order must be the start of some word, and the person who finishes a word without there being a continuation on the word loses. If you are challenged on the letter you say, you lose if you don't have a word, otherwise the challenger loses.

For simplicity, plurals are allowed.

> In the two player version of this game, assuming each player plays optimally who has a winning strategy (the player who goes first or the player who goes second)?

Note that by the fundamental theorem of combinatorial games, we are guaranteed that one player has a winning strategy cannot be a draw.

You are welcome to specify your own dictionary that you would use for 'adjudication' in your answer as long as it is reasonably well-known.

Comment: Isn't this a solved game, or am I thinking of something else?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 It may be, I don't know. I couldn't find it online.

Comment: Nevermind, this is basically the game Ghost with a slight rule change.

Comment: I'm guessing that given any first letter, there is a letter which can be added to it so that creates the first two letters of a three-letter word that cannot be extended. Therefore, I'd guess Player 2 would have the winning strategy if both players played optimally. But since this is only a conjecture, I'm not posting it as an answer.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 What's ghost? Never heard of it.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_(game)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the players use the [Official Tournament and Club Word List](https://www.wordgamedictionary.com/twl06/download/twl06.txt) as their dictionary, then the first player can always force one of the following words:

> jailable 
>  jebels 
>  jiao 
>  jnanas 
>  jodhpurs 
>  juxtaposed 
>  juxtaposes 
>  (I chose j because there's only so many letters it can be continued with.)

I think this strategy also works if they play according to the [OSPD5](http://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/tools#dictionary), but I couldn't find a plaintext version for that, so it's hard to verify.